# Hold PSSession in a global context

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I want to create a few PSSessions and hold them in the background. So later I can connect to a maschine through these PSSessions.

**This should work between different PowerShell instances.**

My very naive approach didn't work.

```
set-variable -name Sessions -value $sessions -scope global
```

Comment: Why not use `Get-PSSession` cmdlet? All sessions can be retrieved this way.

Comment: But the cannot be retrieved between powershell instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to retrieve sessions running in a separate PS instance(that is a process with different PID to the calling process).